# Beginner C programming basic

Tags: c

I have a problem with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()                /* Tidsberäkning YO */
{
    float tid1, tid2;
    printf("Tid i första åket? ");
    scanf("%f", %tid1);
    printf("Tid i andra åket? ");
    scanf(%f", &tid2);
    printf("Total Tid: %f\n", tid1+tid2);
    printf(Genomsnittlig tid: %f\n", (tid1+tid2)/2);
}
```

And here is the error log

```
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(6): error C2059: syntax error : '%'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '%'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): error C2198: 'scanf' : too few arguments for call`
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): error C2001: newline in constant
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): error C2065: 'f' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(8): warning C4552: '%' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(9): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'printf'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): error C2065: 'Genomsnittlig' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): warning C4024: 'printf' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'tid'
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
c:\users\shaggydoo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ilikecake\ilikecake\hellobro.c(10): error C2001: newline in constant
```

Comment: Fixing that mess for you would teach you nothing. What C book are you using ?

Comment: Why won't you read what compiler is telling you? It is pretty clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`scanf(%f", &tid2);`

and

`printf(Genomsnittlig tid: %f\n", (tid1+tid2)/2);`

are missing the first quotation mark. Change to:

`printf("Genomsnittlig tid: %f\n", (tid1+tid2)/2);`

and

`scanf("%f", &tid2);`

Comment: And he's doing `%tid1` in the call to `printf`

Answer (score 5):

Start with the first line of the error messages. It says `(6): error C2059: syntax error : '%'`, which means that line # 6 has an error related to `%`.

So look at line 6 (the first `scanf()` line. Yes, it has a `%` before the variable name, which isn't valid C. Remove it.

Now recompile to remove any stray errors related to the first one,  and look at remaining errors the same way.

Comment: Actually the second error is on line 8, not line 6.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. Thanks for the correction - speed reading isn't always a good thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some `"` and have some unnecessary `%`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an open quote (")

```
scanf("%f", &tid2);
printf("Genomsnittlig tid: %f\n", (tid1+tid2)/2);
```

Use the & not the % in this line

```
scanf("%f", &tid1);
```

Comment: If you give the answer, how does the poster learn anything useful for future use (other than to post a question here and let others fix it)?

Comment: He had correctly used the symbols in some areas. I think he knows to encapsulate strings in quotes, and use the ampersand rather than a percent sign. If the error was in every place, I would have given justification. I guess I should have assumed he knew nothing?

Comment: I think he was just overwhelmed by having 13 errors on 11 lines of code.

Comment: The poster said they knew nothing, and was learning from a book. How do they learn if you give the answer, and they put forth no effort in solving the problem? Instead, point out the direction to solving it themselves, and it's an educational process. If you'd prefer though, I can just downvote because your answer is technically wrong. :)

Comment: Based on what he wrote, I didn't infer any of that.

Comment: Ummm... The question itself? "Beginner C Programming basics" should have been a clue, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%f", %tid1);` you meant to type `scanf("%f", &tid1);`

Answer (score 0):

Basically your punctuation is messed up in many places and that causes a lot of syntax errors.

I'll point out the first couple but I'm not going to hunt down every typo.

On line 6 you have `%tid1` as an expression, which is invalid.  You probably meant `&tid1`.

On line 8 you are missing the opening quotation mark on the first argument to the function.  Same on line 10.

And so on.

Read the error messages and resolve them one at a time.